# No wlan0 in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: networking

I installed Ubuntu 10.04 and I don't have wlan0.

When I type the command

```
lspci -vnn | grep Network
```

I got this result:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. Device [168c:0032] (rev 01)
```

I couldn't find any wifi standards. Could anyone please help me to overcome this issue?

```
iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

ifconfig -a

lo        

eth0

rfkill list all showed nothing as well
```